# mathematica function autocomplete issue

Tags: functions

*This is the default function structure prompt from Mathematica 9*
[image: 1]

*This is my own function module*

```
ExpPDF[PlotName_, FN_] := Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> ToString[FN] <> ".pdf", PlotName]
```

*Using USAGE :*

```
    ExpPDF::usage = "ExpPDF[PlotName,FN] exports image of plot defined by plotname to a specified Filename called FN."
```

*check definition:*
[image: 2]

*Check if autocomplete works:**NO it doesnt prompt for the input arguments***, Is there something wrong in the way I have defined the functions ?

[image: 3]

Comment: Before trying the solution in the duplicate, make sure you have version 9.0.1 (not 9.0.0).

Comment: You need to press Cmd-Shift-K, if I recall correctly

Comment: I think it has to do with 9.0.1